# Does there exist a multiple select dropDownList for asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I'd like to have a DropDownList that has a CheckBox next to each item that would allow multiple to be selected.  I did a little poking around but haven't found anything that will do this, does anyone know if this can be easily achieved?

I know it can be done with a listBox, but would prefer the dropdown format to save space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [DropDown control from the ASP.NET AJAX toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/DropDown/DropDown.aspx): It allows you to put arbitrary controls into a dropdown-like interface. I didn't try it, but I think that it should work to put a CheckBoxList in there.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen a multi-select DropDownList on any platform. How do you want it to work?

I'm sure some clever javascript could create one.